# How to fix the shape of the dashbord, esp. its parts?

Tags: tableau-api

I have built my first dashboard in tableau. When I am logged in and look at this, it looks fine, it consists of 2 horizontal blocks (on the left a double one, on the right it consists of three vizes). When I am logged out and look at the dashboard the right part shows only 1st viz correct, the other two are diminished and you can bearly see them. What might be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few things going on.  Without a picture, it may be one or more of these:

1. Use [Layout
   Containers](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/dashboards_organize_floatingandtiled.htm).
   The layout containers will ensure that each part of the dashboard is
   exactly where you want it relative to a parent container.
2. Use [tiled](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/dashboards_organize_floatingandtiled.htm#tile-or-float-dashboard-items)
   layouts.  Floating layouts may cause dashboard parts to be in different places depending on the screen size.
3. Check to see if you are using Fixed, Automatic or Range [sized](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/dashboards_organize_floatingandtiled.htm#dashboard-size-options) dashboards.  These can also make a difference in appearance based on screen size.
4. If you are using custom fonts, [install them on server](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/customize_fonts.htm) to ensure this isn't a part of the problem.

Please do share a picture (or preferably, the workbook) so further investigation can happen.

Answer (score 0):

In the Dashboard tab -> Layout pane, check the Item hierarchy. 
When a viz/sheet is dragged and dropped on to the dashboard, tableau, by default arranges them in tiled container.

1. If you have adjusted the width manually, disable the option fixed width which is pin symbol when sheet is selected.
2. Make sure that no tiled containers are present and all the sheets are dropped into respective Horizontal containers.
3. Adjust the width of the viz in the sheet to fit in the view.

These are some common resolutions. Share screenshot for much accurate solution.